# Search for multiple text in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with 6 sheets. Sheet 1 is the summary of the other 5 sheets. So basically I need to automate the data entered in sheet 2 - sheet 6 into Sheet 1.

In each sheets I just need to get the count of values that match a certain criteria.

For example:

1. In Sheet2, I just need the count of entries only if the "G" column has the text "Yes" and "H" column has the text "NA" and "K" column has the text "Tablet".
2. This count should be placed in sheet 1 under "AG9" cell. I have to do the same task for many columns.

I have tried the below code and it works fine when it comes to finding a single text and updating in single column. But this does not help with multiple text.

```
Sub WBR()
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Latency") 'sets the worksheet
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = xlSheet.Range("O:O")                       'sets the range to search
    s = "Pass"
    [AE4] = wf.CountIf(r, s)
    s = "Pass" & "Fail"
    [AE3] = wf.CountIf(r, s)
    s = "Fail"
    [AE5] = wf.CountIf(r, s)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is VBA, not VBScript. They're not the same language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `CountIfs` function to do what you want:

```
Sub WBR()
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Latency") 'sets the worksheet
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = xlSheet.Range("O:O")                       'sets the range to search
    s = "Pass"
    [AE4] = wf.CountIf(r, s)
    s = "Pass" & "Fail"
    [AE3] = wf.CountIf(r, s)
    s = "Fail"
    [AE5] = wf.CountIf(r, s)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        [AG9] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Yes", _
                            .Range("H:H"), "NA", _
                            .Range("K:K"), "Tablet")
    End With
End Sub
```

I included a `With` block because I didn't want to keep typing `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").` all the time, and I didn't want to have to create three `Range` objects.

Comment: thank you. Will try out this code.  But how to add more conditions in the same code for different filters and to update the count in different cells?

Comment: I got the answer to include multiple condition. I just added the below code `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT") [AE122] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Not Tested", _ .Range("K:K"), "Tablet") End With` ...Now how will I add another condition that says include rows that has "Tablets" , "Not Tested" but doesn't have "Duplicate" @YowE3K

Comment: @walterwhile - To get "Tablets" / "Not Tested" / not "Duplicate" I think it would be easiest to do `wf.CountIfs(.Range("x:x"), "Tablets", .Range("y:y"), "Not Tested") - wf.CountIfs(.Range("x:x"), "Tablets", .Range("y:y"), "Not Tested", .Range("z:z"), "Duplicate")`

Comment: @walterwhile - No, forget that, `CountIfs` accepts conditions such as `"<>Duplicate"`, so you can just do `wf.CountIfs(.Range("x:x"), "Tablets", .Range("y:y"), "Not Tested", .Range("z:z"), "<>Duplicate")`

Comment: Yes I tried it and it works fine. If I need to select two keywords in a range, lets say in column "x" I need to take the count of cells having "Tablets" and "Non tablets"..Can I just add it as `wf.CountIfs(.Range("x:x"), "Tablets", .Range("X:X"), "Non tablets)`

Comment: @walterwhile - No, that would only count how many had "Tablets" in column X **and** "Non tablets" in column X - which will obviously end up being zero (because it can't have both values at the same time).  For testing for "Tablets" **or** "Non tablets" you will need to add two answers, i.e. `wf.CountIfs(.Range("x:x"), "Tablets") + wf.CountIfs(Range("X:X"), "Non tablets")`

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the answer. This code will work in the workbook where values are present

```
 Sub test1()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim count As Integer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set ws4 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Set ws5 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Set ws6 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet6")


    With Application.WorksheetFunction
       count = .CountIf(ws2.Range("G:G"), "Yes") + _
               .CountIf(ws2.Range("H:H"), "NA") + _
               .CountIf(ws2.Range("K:K"), "Tablet")

    End With

    '"AG9" cell
    ws1.Range("AG9").Value = count


    End Sub
```

Comment: It will need to be `CountIfs` because the three conditions need to be met at the one time.

Comment: @walterwhile - If you have a lot of rows, the error **might** be due to `count` being an `Integer` - would you expect the answer to that query to be more than 32767?  If so, you could change `count` to be declared as `Dim count As Long`.  (Other than that, I can't see a reason for that line to give an error.)